# Quiero imprimir una secuencia de números dentro de una matriz n*n que se imprima de manera diagonal

Tags: java, matriz

Por ejemplo, la secuencia comienza en 1 y tiene que ir avanzando dependiendo hasta donde el usuario quiera, por ejemplo una matriz 3x3, tendría que quedar de tal forma:

- 6  3  1
- 8  5  2
- 9  7  4

Tengo este código que hace lo que quiero pero con un orden diferente y no se como hacer para arreglarlo:

```
int Mat[][] = new int[8][8];
    int f, c, n, v = 1, uFi, uCi;
    String cad;
    n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Introduzca la dimension del vector: "));
    cad = "";
    f = 0;
    c = n - 1;
    uFi = f;
    uCi = c;
    
    do {
        Mat[f][c] = v;
        if(c == n - 1 && uCi > 0) {
            f = 0;
            c = uCi - 1;
            uCi = c;
        }else if(f == n -1 || c == n -1 ) {
            f = uFi + 1;
            c = 0;
            uFi = f;
        }else {
            f++;
            c++;
        }
        v++;
    }while(f != n);
```

Comment: Buenas ¿podrías indicar el código que has realizado? Solo poniendo el enunciado lo mas seguro es que cierren la pregunta, te recomiendo editarlo e indicar hasta donde has llegado y especificar que te falla.

Comment: Buenas, abdiel, bienvenido al sitio. Me temo que esto no es un servicio gratuito de resolución de ejercicios. Si incluyes el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora, quizás se te oriente un poco. En otro caso, es probable que se cierre esta pregunta.

Comment: Échale un ojo a [ask]

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta y añadí un código que tengo, disculpas por los inconvenientes y gracias.